# Columnas dinámicas base de datos

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Estoy dando mantenimiento a un sistema que genera roles de pago, el problema que tengo es que este lee los datos desde un archivo `excel` que varía en número de columnas de acuerdo a los descuentos generados cada mes del rol de pagos, por ejemplo: el mes de enero puede tener 12 descuentos, febrero 8, marzo 13. En otras palabras el archivo `excel` no tiene un formato estable o estático, siempre varía.

El sistema lee directamente estos datos y guarda un archivo `PDF` con el contenido del rol de pago.

Lo que quisiera saber es: **¿Hay alguna forma de almacenar estos datos en una base de datos de tal manera que no importe las columnas de descuentos provenientes del archivo excel?**, ya que el formato del archivo excel varía para cada mes que se genera el rol, y a su vez se guardan cerca de 500 pdf's en disco ocupando demasiado espacio.

Las tecnologías usadas por el sistema son: **php, codeigniter, postgres**.
Referente al código usado por el sistema esta funcionando todo, simplemente quiero optimizar el uso de espacio en disco a través del uso de una base de datos, si es posible.

El código que usa el sistema para leer los datos del excel es el siguiente:

```
require_once './libs/Excel/reader.php';
$mes = $_POST['mes'];
$anio = $_POST['anio'];
$denominacion = $_POST['tipo_persona'];

/*
*      Simple file Upload system with PHP.
*      Created By Tech Stream
*      Original Source at http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Single-File-Upload-With-PHP
*      This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
*      it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
*      the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
*      (at your option) any later version.
*
*      This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*      but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*      MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
*      GNU General Public License for more details.
*
*/
        switch ($denominacion) {
            case 'empleado':
                echo '<section>';
                echo "tipo seleccionado empleado <br />";

                if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) && isset($_FILES['userfile2'])){
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $file_size =$_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['userfile']['type'];
        $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['userfile']['name'])));
                $file_name2 = $_FILES['userfile2']['name'];
        $file_size2 =$_FILES['userfile2']['size'];
        $file_tmp2 =$_FILES['userfile2']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type2=$_FILES['userfile2']['type'];
        $file_ext2=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['userfile2']['name'])));
        $files[] = scandir("./uploads");
        $expensions= array("xls","xlsx");


        if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)&&in_array($file_ext2,$expensions)=== false){
            $errors[]="Extensión no permitida, por favor elija un archivo XLS or XLSX válido.";
        }
        if($file_size > 2097152 && $file_size2 > 2097152){
                    $errors[]='Solo se pueden subir archivos de hasta 2 MB';
        }

                for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
                    for ($j = 0; $j < count($files[$i]); $j++) {
                        if($files[$i][$j] == $file_name){
                            $errors[]='El arhivo ya se encuentra subido';
                        }
                    }

                }

        if(empty($errors)==true){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/var/www/html/roleslogin/uploads/".$file_name);
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp2,"/var/www/html/roleslogin/uploads/".$file_name2);

                    echo '<small>';
                    echo "El archivo ". $_FILES['userfile']['name']. " se subió exitosamente"."</br>";
                    echo "El archivo ". $_FILES['userfile2']['name']. " se subió exitosamente"."</br>";
                    echo '</small>';

                    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

                    $data->setOutputEncoding('utf-8');
                    $data->setRowColOffset(0);

                    $data->read('./uploads/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name']);

                    $cont=0;
                    $a=array();
                    $b=array();
                    $tabla='<table>'.PHP_EOL;
                    for($i=5; $i<$data->sheets[0]['numRows']-2; $i++) {
                        $tabla.="<tr>".PHP_EOL;
                        for($j=1; $j<$data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++){
                            if($i==5){
                                if(isset($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j])){
                                    $tabla.="<th>".PHP_EOL;
                                    $tabla.=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j].PHP_EOL;
                                    $tabla.="</th>".PHP_EOL;
                                    $aux[$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j]]="";
                                }
                            }else{
                                if(isset($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j])){
                                    $tabla.="<td>".PHP_EOL;
                                    $tabla.=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j].PHP_EOL;
                                    $tabla.="</td>".PHP_EOL;
                                    $aux[$data->sheets[0]['cells'][5][$j]]=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j];
                                    $a[$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1]]=$aux;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        $tabla.="</tr>";
                        $cont+=1;
                    }
                    $tabla.="</table>";
                    echo '<div id="tabla1" align="center">';
                    echo $tabla;
                    echo '</div>';

                    //echo "<br/><br/>".$cont;

                    $data2 = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
                    $data2->setOutputEncoding('utf-8');
                    $data2->setRowColOffset(0);
                    $data2->read('./uploads/'.$_FILES['userfile2']['name']);

                    $cont2=0;
                    $tabla2='<table class="flat-table">'.PHP_EOL;
                    for($i=3; $i<$data2->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
                        $tabla2.="<tr>".PHP_EOL;
                        for($j=0; $j<$data2->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++){
                            if($i==3){
                                if(isset($data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j])){
                                    $tabla2.="<th>".PHP_EOL;
                                    $tabla2.=$data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j].PHP_EOL;
                                    $tabla2.="</th>".PHP_EOL;
                                    $aux2[preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j])]="";
                                }
                            }else{
                                if(isset($data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j])){
                                    if($data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j]!=NULL){
                                        if(strlen($data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][0])==10){
                                            $tabla2.="<td>".PHP_EOL;
                                            $tabla2.=$data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j].PHP_EOL;
                                            $tabla2.="</td>".PHP_EOL;
                                            $aux2[preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$data2->sheets[0]['cells'][3][$j])]=trim($data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j]);
                                            $a2[$data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][0]]=$aux2;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    $data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j]=0;
                                    if(strlen($data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][0])==10){
                                        $tabla2.="<td>".PHP_EOL;
                                        //$data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j]=0;
                                        $tabla2.=$data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j].PHP_EOL;
                                        $tabla2.="</td>".PHP_EOL;
                                        $aux2[preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$data2->sheets[0]['cells'][3][$j])]=trim($data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j]);
                                        $a2[$data2->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][0]]=$aux2;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $tabla2.="</tr>";
                        $cont2+=1;
                    }
                    $tabla2.="</table>";
                    echo '<div id="tabla2" align="center">';
                    echo $tabla2;
                    echo '</div>';
                    //echo $cont2;

                    ksort($a);
                    ksort($a2);

                    foreach (array_keys($a2) as $key) {
                        if(!array_key_exists($key,$a)){
                            unset($a2[$key]);
                        }
                    }


                }

                $mes = $_POST['mes'];
                echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
                echo '<div id = "formulario">';
                    echo '<form method="POST" action = "generador.php">'.PHP_EOL;
                        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.  base64_encode(serialize($a)).'" name="ingresos"/>'.PHP_EOL;
                        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.  base64_encode(serialize($a2)).'" name="descuentos"/>'.PHP_EOL;
                        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.  base64_encode(serialize($mes)).'" name="mes"/>'.PHP_EOL;
                        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.  base64_encode(serialize($anio)).'" name="anio"/>'.PHP_EOL;
                        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.  base64_encode(serialize($denominacion)).'" name="denominacion"/>'.PHP_EOL;
                        echo '<input type="submit" value="Guardar" />'.PHP_EOL;
                    echo '</form>'.PHP_EOL;
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</section>';
        }else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
                break;

            default:
                echo 'No existe el tipo de empleado seleccionado <br/>';
                break;
        }
```

Después genera el rol en pdf a través del arreglo enviado por post, mediante este codigo:

```
$ingresos = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['ingresos']));
$descuentos = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['descuentos']));
$mes = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['mes']));
$anio = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['anio']));
$denominacion = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['denominacion']));
$link = new mysqli($server,$usuario,$password,$database);
$acentos = $link->query("SET NAMES 'cp1250'");

$errors="";

$id_aux = "rol-000000";

$keysalarios = array_keys($ingresos);
$keydescuentos = array_keys($descuentos);
$general=array();
if(count($keysalarios) > count($keydescuentos)){
    for($i=0; $i < count($keysalarios); $i++) {
        if(in_array($keysalarios[$i], $keydescuentos)){
            //echo $i.' existe'.$keysalarios[$i]."<br/>";
            $aux_inicial[$i]=$keysalarios[$i];
        }
    }
    $otro = array_values($aux_inicial);

//echo "sal".count($keysalarios)."<br/>";
//echo "des".count($keydescuentos)."<br/>";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($otro); $i++) {
    $key = $otro[$i];
    $keyd = $keydescuentos[$i];
    $value = $ingresos[$key];
    $valued = $descuentos[$keyd];
    $keys2=  array_keys($value);
    $keyd2 = array_keys($valued);

    $general[$otro[$i]]=array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($value); $j++) {
        $llave = $keys2[$j];
        $valor=$value[$llave];
        $general[$otro[$i]][$keys2[$j]]=$valor;
        //echo $keys2[$j].": ".$valor."<br/>";
    }

    for ($j = 2; $j < count($valued); $j++) {
        $llave2 = $keyd2[$j];
        $valor2 = $valued[$llave2];

        $general[$keydescuentos[$i]][$keyd2[$j]]=$valor2;
        //echo $keydescuentos[$i].": ".$keyd2[$j].": ".$valor2."<br/>";
    }
}
}else{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($keysalarios); $i++) {
        $key = $keysalarios[$i];
        $keyd = $keydescuentos[$i];
        $value = $ingresos[$key];
        $valued = $descuentos[$keyd];
        $keys2=  array_keys($value);
        $keyd2 = array_keys($valued);

        $general[$keysalarios[$i]]=array();
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($value); $j++) {
            $llave = $keys2[$j];
            $valor=$value[$llave];
            $general[$keysalarios[$i]][$keys2[$j]]=$valor;
            //echo $keys2[$j].": ".$valor."<br/>";
        }

        for ($j = 2; $j < count($valued); $j++) {
            $llave2 = $keyd2[$j];
            $valor2 = $valued[$llave2];

            $general[$keydescuentos[$i]][$keyd2[$j]]=$valor2;
            //echo $keydescuentos[$i].": ".$keyd2[$j].": ".$valor2."<br/>";
        }
    }

}

switch ($denominacion) {
    case 'empleado':
        $query = "INSERT INTO persona(cedula,nombres,mod_laboral)VALUES(";

        foreach ($ingresos as $key => $value) {
            $existe = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT cedula FROM persona WHERE cedula='".$key."'");
            if($existe->num_rows == 0){
                foreach ($value as $key2 => $valor) {
                    switch (utf8_decode($key2)) {
                        case "IDENTIFICACI?N":
                            $query.="'".$valor."',";
                            break;
                        case "NOMBRES";
                            $query.="'".$valor."',";
                            break;
                        case "MODALIDAD LABORAL":
                            $query.="'".$valor."')";
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    //echo $key2." ".$valor;
                }
                $aux = $query or die("Error en la consulta " . mysqli_error($link));
                //echo $aux;
                if(mysqli_query($link, $aux)){
                    $errors = "";
                }else{
                    $errors.= 'Error: ' . mysqli_error($link)." "."</br>";
                }
            }else{

            }
        }

        $keygeneral = array_keys($general);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($keygeneral); $i++) {
            $key = $keygeneral[$i];
            $value = $general[$key];
            //echo $keygeneral[$i];
            $keyg =  array_keys($value);

            $existe = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT cedula FROM persona WHERE cedula='".$key."'");
            if($existe->num_rows != 0){
                //echo $i." existe ".$key."<br/>";
                //Creacion PDF
                $pdf = new mipdf(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'UTF-8', false);
                // set document information
                $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
                $pdf->SetAuthor('Juan Pinzon');
                $pdf->SetTitle('Prueba Roles');
                $pdf->SetSubject('Roles');
                $pdf->SetKeywords('Roles, prefectura, pdf');

                // set default header data
                $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH);

                // set header and footer fonts
                $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
                $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

                // set default monospaced font
                $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

                // set margins
                $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
                $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
                $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

                // set auto page breaks
                $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

                // set image scale factor
                $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

                // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
                if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
                        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
                        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
                }

                // ---------------------------------------------------------

                // set font
                $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

                // add a page
                $pdf->AddPage();

                $porcentajeiess=0.1445;

                $html='<div align="center"><h1><u>Rol de Pagos Individual</u></h1></div>';
                $html.='<div align="right">'.ucwords($mes)." ".$anio.'</div>';
                $html.='<br/><br/>';
                $html.='<table border="1" align="left">';
                $rmu = 0;
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($value); $j++) {
                    $llave=$keyg[$j];
                    $valor=$value[$llave];
                    //echo $keyg[$j]." ".$valor;
                    //echo "<br/>";
                    $html .= '<tr>';
                    for ($k = 0; $k < 1; $k++) {
                        if($keyg[$j]!="APORTE PATRONAL"){
                            if($keyg[$j]=="INGRESOS"){
                                $rmu=$valor;
                            }
                            $html .= '<td>';
                            $html .= '<b>'.$keyg[$j].'</b>';
                            $html .= '</td>';
                            $html .= '<td>';
                            $html .= $valor;
                            $html .= '</td>';
                        }else{

                            $html .= '<td bgcolor="#386F9A" colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">';
                            $html.="<b><br/>DESGLOSE DE DESCUENTOS</b><br/>";
                            $html .= '</td>';

                        }
                    }
                    $html .= '</tr>';
                    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                    // Print a table

                }
                $html .= '<tr>';
                $html .= '<td>';
                $html .= '<b>Aporte IESS</b>';
                $html .= '</td>';
                $html .= '<td>';
                $html .= round($rmu * $porcentajeiess, 2);
                $html .= '</td>';
                $html .= '</tr>';
                $html.='</table>';

                $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, 45, 20, $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

                $pdf->lastPage();

                //grabar direccion pdf en db
                //$direccion="/pdfroles/".$keygeneral[$i]."-".$mes."-".date("Y").".pdf";

                //generar pdf
                $pdf->Output('/home/hd/pdfroles/'.$keygeneral[$i].'-'.$mes.'-'.$anio.'.pdf', 'F');
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Hola @juan1992. Debes especificar que tecnologías usas y postear el código relevante para poderte ayudar. En el estado actual de la pregunta es imposible reproducir tu problema y brindarte una solución. Lee http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Ok, no hay problema, ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Estan las tecnologías pero aun no hay nada de código. Si lees los links que te puse verás que debes crear un ejemplo minimo verificable que reproduzca tu problema sino la ayuda es imposible. De lo contrario tu pregunta puede ser cerrada por ser demasiado amplia.

Comment: Ok, gracias por las recomendaciones, ya puse el código usado.

Comment: Estimado: nosotros usamos una lógica para eso, además del código, se sube el archivo físico, se procesa usando una librería, luego se inserta en una BD (esto sería como un 'mantenedor de carga') luego, en otra opción, puedes manipular según lo que necesites (generar pdf, en este caso). Ten ojo ya que mi experiencia en codeigniter, es que no acepta bien las cargas de datos masivas como las que genera -por ejemplo- un excel. Si gustas se comento el código como respuesta.

Comment: Hola @h40s4m4 gracias por comentar, claro si puedes compartir alguna respuesta sería muy útil.

Answer (score 3):

Una posible solución podría ser pasar los datos a una estructura de tabla similar a esta:

```
------------------------
| ID | MES | Descuento |
| 1  | ENE |     20    |
| 2  | ENE |     40    |
| 3  | ENE |     50    |
| 4  | FEB |     22    |
| 5  | FEB |     45    |
| 6  | FEB |     10    |
| 7  | FEB |     35    |
------------------------
```

Cuando lees el excel generarías un insert por cada columna, el ID es auto generado. El mes te sirve para recuperar y regenerar el pdf que tenés que mostrar luego al cliente. Tendrías que incluir por lo menos el año, esto te va a servir para que los datos después no se mezclen cuando tengas mas de un año de información. También agregar un index a la table por esas dos columnas (año, mes) para mejorar la velocidad en las consultas.

Comment: Gracias por responder, me parece una buena manera de hacerlo, lo voy a probar, luego te comento los resultados, :)